# (Unity) How to check if animation is playing in a Blend Tree?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get specific directional attack animations to play when a 2D sprite is in a specific directional idle animation. So for example, if the sprite is in the up-right idle animation, I'd like to play the up-right attack animation.

I tried checking to see if that animation is playing in Mecanim and then play the attack animation like so, but no good:

```
 if(this.anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Idle_UpRight.Idle")){

        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
            Debug.Log("Attack right");
        }

    }
```

The "Idle_UpRight" animation is buried in the Idle 2D Freeform Cartesian blend tree. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Unity tag has nothing to do with Unity3d game engine on stack overflow. Please don't use it with this kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

Since `xlidle` is Layer Blend Tree and `IdleDownLeft` is an animation,
they does not have any effects.

```
void findlayerAnimator()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < myani.layerCount; i++)
    {
        if(myani.GetLayerName(i) == "XLIdle")
        {
            if (this.myani.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(i).IsName("XLIdle.IdleDownLeft"))
            {
                Debug.Log("Goodsadsadsaff");
            }
        }

    }

}
```